# pyBluez python server - phone don't see my server

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, nokia, bluez

first i'm sorry if my english is not very good because i'm french.

I'm a beginner on bluetooth development with pyBluez (i already know TCP and UDP sockets) and i have a little problem with the server.
when i run the following code, my computer seems to be in a listening state but when my phone(nokia xpress music 5800) try to detect it, it doesn't see anything!

and there is two surprising things for me:
1)there is no fonction in my code configuring a name like "my computer". maybe my phone find my address but,because it can't resolve the name by lookup_name()-like function, it considers my computers isn't on?

2)when i replace `serversock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))` by `serversock.bind(("00:12:34:56:78:9A",PORT_ANY))` where 00:12:34:56:78:9A is the address given by hciconfig tool for my bluetooth device, i'm getting : 
`_bluetooth.error: (98, 'Address already in use'`

just a stupid question because i think the answer is yes bacause of channels:
is it possible to have multiple program listening on the SAME bluetooth interfaces.

i run the program on root

```
from bluetooth import *
serversock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
serversock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
serversock.listen(1)
advertise_service(serversock,"SampleServer",service_classes = [ SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ] )
clientsock,clientinfo = serversock.accept()
print "Accepted connection from " , clientinfo
clientsock.send("PyBluez server says Hello!! ")
data = clientsock.recv(1024)
print "received: " , data
clientsock.close()
serversock.close()
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the server's visibility with `hciconfig`:

```
# hciconfig

hci0:   Type: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:12:34:56 ACL MTU: 192:8  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN
    RX bytes:296 acl:0 sco:0 events:26 errors:0
    TX bytes:536 acl:0 sco:0 commands:22 errors:0
```

In case your local device is invisible, set visibility on with:

```
hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

Turn off visibility if needed with:

```
hciconfig hci0 noscan
```